# Ionic 3 - changes in json files are not seen until i 'serve' again

Tags: constructor

I have an `Ionic 3` project.

Inside of assets folder, I have some `JSON` files. If I do any changes in any of this files, the ionic client will detect that some changes have been done, it will recompile, but when I access within the code the content of the `JSON` is not changed. Seems like somehow is cached?

If I serve again, everything will be ok.

The `i18n` files are stored in the assets folder as well. Any changes to those files will recompile the project and will be displayed within the project without a need to serve again. How do I do this for my custom `JSON` files?

Example:

```
assets/data/languages.json [{"title": "en-us"}]
```

pages/installer.ts

```js
import * as languages from '../../assets/data/languages.json';

export class InstallerPage {


 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  console.log(languages);
 }
  
}
```

If I do any changes to the languages.json, it automatically recompiles, but when accessing the installer page, the changes won't be displayed when logging to console. They will only be displayed correctly after I reserve.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: do you use service worker in your Ionic?

Comment: I was using the default serviceWorker that comes when starting a project. Tried without it. Using it or not doesn't make any difference to my issue.